# Problems in setting up VirtualHost using WAMP server

Tags: apache, dns, virtualhost, wampserver

I want to host multiple websites on my computer. I'm using Windows with WAMP server. I already have domains and know how to map them to ip.
I have already edited httpd.conf file to allow virtual hosts.

My httpd-vhosts file looks like this,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "C:/wamp64/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/testcase"
  ServerName test.mydomain.com
  <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/testcase">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/test2"
    ServerName test2.mydomain.com
    <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/test2">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that both my domains open only the first site in this VirtualHost tag. 
Example: In this case, both my domains will open the WAMP server configuration page. If I were to move the "testcase" tag above the other, both my domains will open the "testcase" page.

Update:
My subdomains show corresponding pages successfully when I open them on the server. But when I open subdomains on another machine, they open the first entry in the VH.

> Update 2: Okay, so this is just out of my understanding now. I thought may be WAMP is not my cup of tea. So I installed XAMPP and made changes to the VH configuration and still ended up with same problem. So I then got rid of XAMPP too and installed WAMPDeveloper Pro. What could go wrong when the software sets up all the configuration files for you, right? But to my surprise, I still have the same problem. The websites work fine when I open them (using actual domain name) on the server itself, but when I open them on machine outside network the first VH entry open for all the domains I open.

Can anyone please help me with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using both Apache2.2 and Apache2.4 syntax gets Apache a litle confused.

So as I assume you are running Apache 2.4 change the VH defs to this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/testcase"
  ServerName test.mydomain.com
  <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/testcase">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/test2"
    ServerName test2.mydomain.com
    <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/test2">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All

      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Why Apache opens the first site i.e. localhost in this case.

If Apache cannot make sense of a VH def, it ignores it and default to loading the first Virtual Host that was correctly defined in the httpd-vhosts.conf file.

Of course you will also need to amend your `c:\windows\system32\driverrs\etc\hosts` file to include these domain names

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 test.mydomain.com
127.0.0.1 test2.mydomain.com

::1 localhost
::1 test.mydomain.com
::1 test2.mydomain.com
```

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, Thanks for your answer! I tried to use the syntax you sent but it still doesn't work. Both the domains are showing only the top most VirtualHost entry. And yes, I'm using Apache version 2.4.

Comment: See notes on the HOSTS file requirements, I assumed you had these already, but maybe you do not.

Comment: Yes, my host file is configured in correct manner. But still its not working. Do you have any other suggestions?